# jsch sftp - change to parent directory

Tags: java, android, sftp, jsch

I'm trying to figure out how to figure out how to go to the parent directory using Jsch Sftp.

I have the current path stored in a string and I'm guessing that channelSftp.cd(String); is what I should use. But using substring on the current path I have feels wrong. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same as in the shell:

```
channelSftp.cd("..");
```